# "no such function: floor " when run within Python but the SELECT statement runs without issue when I type it in to sqlite3.exe

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sql statement that runs without error when I type it in to the sqlite3, but if I run it through my python script, it fails to recognize floor as a function.

I have a data set that contains the unix time (epoch), number of writes, and I want to capture the sum of the writes in various timed intervals.  (10m, 20m, 1h, 2h etc).  In this example, I am using 30m sample (1800 seconds).  Here is the working SELECT Statement and the output when I run it sqlite3.exe

```
sqlite> SELECT "123456789" as ArraySN,
   ...> strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', datetime(tsecs, 'unixepoch')) as "Date   Time",
   ...> floor(tsecs/1800) * 1800 as "epoch",
   ...> 'W' as "R/W", sum(wsize5) as "16k"
   ...> FROM statvlun GROUP BY "Array SN", "epoch"
   ...> ORDER BY "epoch";
```

```
123456789|2021-03-03 05:20:00|1614747600|W|14410640.0
123456789|2021-03-03 05:30:00|1614749400|W|43205476.0
123456789|2021-03-03 06:00:00|1614751200|W|43193768.0
123456789|2021-03-03 06:30:00|1614753000|W|42348397.0
123456789|2021-03-03 07:00:00|1614754800|W|43197724.0
123456789|2021-03-03 07:30:00|1614756600|W|43196195.0
123456789|2021-03-03 08:00:00|1614758400|W|28802535.0
```

However, if I attempt to run this same query from python, it complains about the floor function not being recognized.  I looked for special characters, tried single quotes, double quotes, triple quotes, encapsulating in the entire floor statement in parenthesis, and tried pandas vs sqlite3 module.  Here is the sample code that I am running:

```
def main():
    sql = """
    SELECT "123456789" as ArraySN,
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', datetime(tsecs, 'unixepoch')) as \"Date   Time\",
    floor(tsecs/1800) * 1800 as "epoch",
    'W' as "R/W", sum(wsize5) as "16k"
    FROM statvlun GROUP BY "Array SN", "epoch"
    ORDER BY \"epoch\";
    """

    print(sql)
    primdb_file = "testdb.db"
    primdb_cnxn = sqlite3.connect(primdb_file)
    cur = primdb_cnxn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    results = cur.fetchall()
    print(results)
```

and I get `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: floor`

Here is the full output of the test script.  What am I missing here?!?!

```
> python .\testsql.py

SELECT "123456789" as ArraySN,
strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', datetime(tsecs, 'unixepoch')) as "Date   Time",
floor(tsecs/1800) * 1800 as "epoch",
'W' as "R/W", sum(wsize5) as "16k"
FROM statvlun GROUP BY "Array SN", "epoch"
ORDER BY "epoch";


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\testsql.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\testsql.py", line 29, in main
    cur.execute(sql)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: floor
```

Answer (score 4):

Inclusion of the math functions are a compile-time option.  The DLL that Python builds does not include them.  You can get the same results by casting to an integer, `CAST(tsecs/1800 AS INTEGER)`.